# Flash AS3 - removeChild() used to completely delete object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, object, removechild

I'm creating an asteroids game and in my main class I'm having some trouble handling the bullets that the ship fires.

All of the bullets are of the "Bullet" class and are stored in an array called "bullets" in the main class. When bullets exit the screen, removeBullet(bulletID) in the main class is called.

```
private function removeBullet(id:int)
    {
        removeChild(bullets[id]);
        bullets.splice(id);
    }
```

In my Bullet class I have an enterFrame listener that traces "stillHere". So as soon as a bullet is added to the main stage using addChild, "stillHere" starts popping up in my output panel.

My problem is that even after I call the removeBullet, "stillHere" keeps popping up in the output panel, which tells me that the object which I tried to delete is still sticking around somewhere in the memory.

What can I do to get rid of it completely?

Comment: Hi, are you sure that bullets[id] returns the reference to the Bullet instance? Try to trace( bullets[id] ) to check if it's not undefined.

Comment: Yes it does. The function successfully removes the bullet visually from the screen too.

Comment: have you heard of object pools? There a couple of implementations ready to use and you can make your own too, for this sort of stuff (bullets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are in ActionScript you have no direct control over when objects get removed.

The real problem you have is that your event listeners are still firing. You can obviously solve this by calling `removeEventListener` when they are deleted.

However **a better approach** is to have just one `ENTER_FRAME` listener for the whole game. It will need to individually advance all the game elements (ship, asteroids, bullets, debris etc). This method removes any chances of you accidentally forgetting to remove event listeners, and it also makes the code clearer since you can see the order that elements will update within a time step.

I usually have a `destroy` function in my temporary objects which reads something like this:

```
public function destroy():void {
    stop(); // if it's a MovieClip
    if(parent) parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

As long as I call this function and then remove references to the object, it's usually collected.

My code very rarely has listeners on individual objects for this reason.

Comment: +1 For suggesting that there should only be one ENTER_FRAME listener in the entire application.  Great advice.

Comment: A year and a half later, thanks for the good advice on the single event listener. I didn't get it at the time but in hindsight this would've been the best choice.

Answer (score 4):

The event listener itself could very well be the reason it's still in memory.  That is not a good way to test whether something has been garbage collected or not.

Also, even if that were a good way to check whether an object has been garbage collected, collection is not an instantaneous process.  The Flash Player will only run the gc when it needs to allocate more memory and fails to do so.

Assuming you have no other references to the bullet object besides the display list and the bullets array, what you've done is sufficient to allow it to be garbage collected.

EDIT : To answer the question as to whether there's any way to observe whether an object has been collected...

You can use the object as the *key* in a weakly keyed dictionary.

```
private var _dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
_dict[bullet] = "Bullet is still here...";
```

Then whenever you want to check whether the bullet still exists, you use a for...in loop to iterate the keys

```
for(var key:* in _dict){
    trace(key + " " + _dict[key]);
}
```

Because a weakly keyed dictionary's keys do not count as references for the purposes of garbage collection, this works.

If you're very concerned about memory leaks, you might consider writing an object pool into which you place old bullet objects that you remove from the stage, and simply re-use them over and over.  In this way you'll *never* allow any bullets to be garbage collected, but you'll probably only ever create a small, limited number of bullets (that being the number of bullets the user ever sees onscreen simultaneously at a given time).  This might be the best solution for you as the bullets probably have a small memory footprint and you get the bonus of not forcing Flash to clean up your garbage.  Running the GC causes performance degradation while the garbage is being removed, so by that measure doing what you can to prevent even needing it is a good thing.

Comment: If I add in:

'bullets[id].removeEventListener(eventListenerName);'

will there be another way to check wether it has been collected or not?

Comment: I'm just worried that objects that are supposed to be deleted are going to continue running functions which may affect the main program.

Comment: Yes, there is a round-about way to do this.  I'll edit my answer, as it requires some better formatting than the comment space allows.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson + tips! Much appreciated!